# Why IntelliJ shows I have an error when I refer to a project in build.sbt?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

[image]

I find that can't create project in my build.sbt. expect someone help me to resolve it, thanks very much!

Comment: just idea report it error, I can user sbt normally with out error

Answer (score 1):

I also notice that IntelliJ (up to v14.1.3) reports incorrect errors when editing `build.sbt` files. It's best if you do the edits in IntelliJ and then test everything from the command line.

Note: If you have SBT constantly running in a shell, don't forget to do a `reload` each time you edit your sbt files.